# Gcloud source repository trying to push local to remote and command uses wrong username / credentials

Tags: git, gcloud

I have a local git repo that I'm trying to push to a Gcloud source repo that I've created.  Everything seems to be fine, except for when I try to push I get:

`fatal: remote error: Access denied to email1@example.com`

I've gone thru [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart) to get gcloud to use correct git credentials, but to no avail.  I currently have 2 gcloud configurations on my computer, and have set the second configuration to be active.  However, running `git push google master` to push to gcloud source repo will always try to use `email1` which is for configuration 1.  I want to use `email2` which is for configuration 2 - the active configuration - but I can't figure out how and can't seem to find any docs on it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does `gcloud source repos clone` use an `https://` URL, or an `ssh://` URL? If the former, does the URL embed a `username:password@host` part, or not? If not, what credentials does your operating system offer for username and password, and how do you control those?

Comment: I haven't cloned any repo from GCR.  The git repo is local on my machine, and I added a remote via `git remote add google url-of-my-gcr-remote`

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar behaviour and the problem in my case was caused by `~/.gitcookies` file containing stored credentials for "email1@example.com"

After editing/removal of this file, git started correctly using gcloud credentials helper.

Comment: This solved the gcloud permission issue related to git for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
$ gcloud source repos clone hello-world
```

in current configuration, gcloud will under the hood set git credential helper to always point to same account the repository was cloned with. You can see it with

```
$ git config -l

credential.helper=!gcloud.cmd auth git-helper --account=email1@example.com --ignore-unknown $@
```

So later switching `gcloud` configurations or setting new `gcloud` account will not change how this repo is authenticated.

I am not sure why you want to clone repo with email1 and then push to it with email2.

You can always change this be running

```
$ git config credential.helper \
  '!gcloud.cmd auth git-helper --account=email2@example.com --ignore-unknown $@'
```

If you want for some reason to always use active configuration, simply omit `--account` when setting credential helper.

Answer (score 0):

[`gcloud source repos clone`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/source/repos/clone) clones a git repository from the currently active Google Cloud project into the specified directory or into the current directory if no target directory is specified.
The clone operation configures the local clone to use your gcloud credentials to authenticate future git operations.

This should be an https URL, which means there is a credential helper which caches the credentials (username/password)

In your cloned repository, type:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If it is not `git-credential-gcloud.cmd` (as [in this issue](https://github.com/prototipando/google-cloud-sdk/issues/431#issuecomment-196136286)) or if `git-credential-gcloud.cmd` is not in your `%PATH%` (`where git-credential-gcloud.cmd` should return a path), it would not work.
Note: now the credential helper might [be called simply **`gcloud.cmd`**](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes)

```
git config credential.https://source.developers.google.com.helper
```

If you don't have access to `gcloud.cmd`, you will need to [generate static credentials](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes).

Comment: I haven't cloned any repo from GCR. The git repo is local on my machine, and I added a remote via `git remote add google url-of-my-gcr-remote`.  Also, I'm using mac.

Comment: @Murcielago That might be the issue. Try instead, for testing, cloning a repo from GCR instead of going the opposite route.

Comment: 1.  I still should be able to add a GCR repo as a remote to an existing local git repo according to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes).  2.  At your suggestion, I tried cloning the empty GCR repo to my machine with `gcloud source repos clone my-grc-repo`, and it returns the same error:  `fatal: remote error: Access denied to email1`

Comment: @Murcielago I agree: this is for testing only. What does `gcloud source repos list` return? And what account are you using (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/)?

Comment: `gcloud source repos list` return expected result:  the repos that are for account/configuration for `email2`.  `gcloud info` also returns expected output: Account: `email2`
Project: `project-for-email2`

Comment: @Murcielago then the docker credential helper (named gcloud: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5875#issuecomment-383090072) is caching email1 as credential. (beside that, you current active account is email2, right?: https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/c7747c77f6d8afe7c1d02896d46e2480967152c8/lib/surface/topic/escaping.py#L33-L38)

Comment: I'm not sure what docker credential helper has to do with this?  This issue is coming up for `git push` to google cloud source repo.  I mistakenly said `gcr`, but I meant google cloud source repository as I said in my initial question.  But anyway, I'm able to push docker images from my local machine to my google cloud container registry as expected. It's just the git push that failes

Comment: Ok. Again, I think it is a got credential helper, called gcloud.cmd, which incorrectly proposes the wrong email. I don't have access to a gcr environment, so I cannot fully test that theory.

Comment: On mac the credential helper is `gcloud.sh`.  I'm just not sure why it's using this other email.  I'm about to delete/uninstall gcloud and try again, but damn, what a headache!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check would be the permission on IAM on Google cloud for the user attempting to write to the GCR. To write to the Google Cloud Repository (GCR) you will need to have the correct permissions assigned prior to writing to the repository. When you use the gcloud sdk, the user credentials need to match with that in the IAM or you will encounter a lot of permission denied messages.

If you are unable to use the gcloud interface to access GCR, then you can test interaction using the cloud shell interface which will have the necessary service account access to your project. Personally, I would recommend using cloud shell in most cases over connecting through gcloud SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The issue is not strictly permissions.  It's that from the gcloud SDK (using CLI on my local computer) whenever I try to `git push` to the GCR repo, at some level the wrong username is being used.  I have 2 gcloud project configs, and it seems like "no matter what I do", the `git push` command to remote GCR always uses the wrong username (it uses `email1` instead of `email2`.  Also, `git push` to a github repo owned by `email2` works as expected.

Comment: Ok, credentials are managed via SSH key. Ensure the is a role in IAM on Google cloud first. Then do gcloud init from your command line to set the correct credentials you wish to use based on the available profiles setup in IAM. These should match to your project settings for GCR. Hope that helps?

Comment: Yeah, this is already done.  It clearly shows that `email2` is the current active config being used, and there's no other issues with performing any other remote operations - they all use `email2` correctly.  The only issue is pushing to gcr remote.  It still tries to use `email1`.  Is there something about when you first install gcloud SDK that hard codes the first provided account details somewhere?  I initially set up with `email1`.

Comment: Have you also used gcloud init to reset the account context to the one you want (tell it which account to use)?

Comment: Yes, I have done that.  And  `gcloud config configurations list` shows correct one is active.  In fact, it doesn't even list the one with `email1` any more (I think I removed it in all of this mess).  So I'm thinking it's hardcoded somewhere in a config file that I can't find.

Comment: In which case, is possibly your git config. Have you tried git config -- list to confirm you are passing the correct credentials?